# How to Access from Selenium changing HTML

Tags: javascript, c#, html, selenium

writing the code in c# selenium. I modified ID, tag, and class xpath to  for the purpose of automatically writing comments in the comment box. but it says I can't find the location. So I kept looking at the code and the tag on Div changed when I approached the text. I wonder how to approach and write in this situation.

when do not touch text
[image]

whentouch code
[image]

As you can see
 Class:u_cbox_write_wrap u_cbox_focus =>u_cbox_write_wrap u_cbox_focus u_cbox_writing
and 
style="display: block; => style="display: none;

how can i access to this.....
I'm desperate for your help.

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

You can use div that is immediate child of div that is changing ""

OR

I believe textarea has ID itself that can be used for identification.

Comment: Can  you share locator  you are using?